# Amazon Corretto 8 Container awareness

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, corretto

After reading *all* AWS Documentation about Amazon Corretto, I have found no clue of JVM options to enable container awareness (if it is not enabled by default) and option names to control container memory usage ratio for heap when running on a (Docker) container.

Does anyone knows how to configure these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Corretto has the same Container support that Open JDK does.  It's enabled by default in the latest version, or you can explicitly specify by using the following flag:

```
-XX:+UseContainerSupport
```